# If don‘t expose port, how does docker DNAT work?

Tags: docker, docker-network

For example, I wget a web page in a docker container which doesn't expose any port. I know that iptables SNAT charges to transform container's IP to host's IP. But when container gets repose, Who charges to transform host' IP to contaniner's?

Comment: If you don't _publish_ a port (`docker run -p` option, Compose `ports:`) then the container won't be accessible except from other containers on the same network.  _Exposing_ a port means almost nothing in modern Docker.

Answer (score 0):

This is all managed by host kernel. It applies NAT rules to outgoing packets and remembers to replace its ip with container's ip when the response is received.